# Why is the runtime of this code O(n^5)?

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

I have been asked to determine the big-O time complexity of this code:

```
function(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < i * i; j++) {
            if (j % i == 0) {
                for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
                    printf("*");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The answer given is **O(n<sup>5</sup>)**. Can anyone explain why, or how to determine this? Do we add the number of times innermost loop works, or do we multiply the complexities of each loop?

Comment: Can you provide a source on the O(n^5) answer? Where did this come from, and what explanation did they give?

Comment: This question was given in the book Data structures and algorithms made easy by Narasimha Karumanchi. The explanation is that outermost loop executes n times, the middle one nxn times and the innermost nxn times. Then he said that the total complexity is O n^5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to analyze code like this is to start from the innermost loop and work outward. That loop is

```
    for (int k=0; k<j; k++)
    {
      printf("*");
    }
```

This has time complexity Θ(j). So now let's look at the next loop:

```
for (int j=i; j<i*i; j++)
{
    if (j%i==0)
    {
      // do Theta(j) work
    }
}
```

This one is interesting. This loop will run Θ(i<sup>2</sup>) times. Most iterations will do O(1) work, but every ith iteration will do Θ(j) work. We can therefore separate the work done here into two pieces: the baseline Θ(i<sup>2</sup>) work done just from looping a lot, plus the extra work done from intermittently doing Θ(j) work.

That part where we do Θ(j) work happens every i iterations. This means that work done will be roughly

> i + 2i + 3i + 4i + ... + i<sup>2</sup>
>
> = i(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + i)
>
> = iΘ(i<sup>2</sup>)
>
> = Θ(i<sup>3</sup>)

So overall, this loop does Θ(i<sup>3</sup>) work. This dominates the Θ(i<sup>2</sup>) work from the outer loop, so the total work done here is Θ(i<sup>3</sup>).

Finally, we can work our way to the outermost loop, which looks like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    // Do Theta(i^3) work
}
```

The work done here is roughly

> 0<sup>3</sup> + 1<sup>3</sup> + 2<sup>3</sup> + 3<sup>3</sup> + ... + (n-1)<sup>3</sup>
>
> = Θ(n<sup>4</sup>)

So overall, the total work done here is **Θ(n<sup>4</sup>).** This is a tighter bound than the O(n<sup>5</sup>) given in the problem statement, so either

1. I have a math error somewhere in here, or
2. the bound you have isn't tight.

Remember that big-O notation is used to give an upper bound on the runtime of a piece of code, so saying that the runtime is O(n<sup>5</sup>) if the runtime is actually Θ(n<sup>4</sup>) isn't wrong; it's just not tight. It wouldn't be wrong to say it's O(n<sup>100</sup>) either, though this isn't a very useful bound.

One way we can check this is to write a program that just counts up how many times the innermost loop runs and to compare that against n<sup>4</sup> for various values of n. I wrote a program that does just that. It's shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
 #include <cstdint>
 #include <cmath>
 using namespace std;
 
 uint64_t countWork(int n) {
   uint64_t result = 0;
 
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     for (int j = 1; j < i * i; j++) {
       if (j % i == 0) {
        for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
          result++;
        }
      }
    }
   }
 
   return result;
 }

 int main() {
   for (int n = 100; n <= 1000; n += 100) {
     cout << "Ratio of work to n^4 when n = "
          << n << " is " << countWork(n) / pow(double(n), 4.0) 
          << endl;
   }
 }
```

Here's the output:

```
Ratio of work to n^4 when n = 100 is 0.120871
Ratio of work to n^4 when n = 200 is 0.122926
Ratio of work to n^4 when n = 300 is 0.123615
Ratio of work to n^4 when n = 400 is 0.123961
Ratio of work to n^4 when n = 500 is 0.124168
Ratio of work to n^4 when n = 600 is 0.124307
Ratio of work to n^4 when n = 700 is 0.124406
Ratio of work to n^4 when n = 800 is 0.12448
Ratio of work to n^4 when n = 900 is 0.124537
Ratio of work to n^4 when n = 1000 is 0.124584
```

From this it looks like the runtime is roughly approaching 0.125n<sup>4</sup>, which is roughly n<sup>4</sup> / 8. That actually makes sense - the hidden constant factor from the innermost loop is 1/2 (since 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + i = i(i+1)/2) and the hidden constant factor from the outermost loop is 1/4 (since 1<sup>3</sup> + 2<sup>3</sup> + ... + n<sup>3</sup> = n<sup>2</sup>(n + 1)<sup>2</sup> / 4). In other words, the theory really closely matches the practice!

Comment: @kpie I assumed that the OP was asking for the big-O time complexity of the runtime of the code, since I'm not sure what other quantity they'd be talking about. The main thing I'm interested in is making sure that my math is correct, though. Do you see anything that looks amiss?

Comment: As I understand it and I might be off here ( much respect to the 177k and all) but the O is the worst case as in without considering conditionals, and the run-time of the function is limited <= O

Comment: @kpie While you can get a conservative upper bound on the runtime by multiplying all the loops together, that isn't in general a good way to determine the runtime of a function. You can get a more precise bound - which is what I'm trying to do here - by being more careful with how much work each loop actually does. Again, I'm pretty sure the math is right, which is why I'm trying to see why I'm getting a different answer than what the OP suggests.

Comment: lets continue this in chat...
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103786/time-complexity

Comment: Dear @templatetypedef, time complexity for this question is `O(n^5)`. You can see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

So the O time complexity is the product of the maximum individual iteration count for each loop nested in terms of an arbitrary variable n of interest.

Here you have

```
function (int n) // as in O(n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) //  n
    {
    for(int j=i;j<i*i;j++) // n ^ 2
       {

         if(j%i==0) // w/e
           {
             for(int k=0;k<j;k++) // n ^ 2
              {
                printf("*");
              }
            }
       }

     }
}
```

**n * n^2 * n^2 = n^5**

Interestingly you will find that the number of "*" printed is not n^5 what ever, this is a consequence if the if condition, you will find for a given positive int n the count of * will be < n ^ 5 and potentially > n ^ 4 .

By using the product of the maximum number of iterations for each loop we can quickly get the ceiling of the end behavior of a function as n increases arbitrarily.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematical form for total time complexity of this question in a worst case is as follow:

[image]

> So complexity is `O(n^5)`.

**Edit:** In above answer I don't attention to `if` performance.

We can change your code as follow:

```
function(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < i * i; j+=i) {
                for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
                    printf("*");
                }
        }
    }
}
```

So,as templatetypedef  mentioned, it is evident that total runtime is `O(n^4)`.

Comment: I think that like the earlier answer this ignores the impact of the if statement on the time complexity. I'm pretty sure that you have a valid answer that isn't tight, and the fact that the program I wrote empirically backs up my mathematical analysis leads me to believe that my answer is correct.

Comment: Dear @templatetypedef, You are right. thanks for your good point.